# Database Exception with Sprout Forms after updating to Craft 3

Tags: craft3, database, error, plugin-sproutforms

I've recently updated a site from Craft 2 to 3. I'm getting this error after login in to the admin regarding Sprout Forms which was installed in my Craft 2 install.
What can I do to get the back-end functioning again? The front-end is fine apart from the pages which contained sprout forms, which I've removed.

```
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'sproutforms_forms.saveData' in 'field list'
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sproutforms_forms.saveData' in 'field list'
in (path)/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 1258
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is often caused if you don't first update Sprout Forms to v2.5.1 before the upgrade to Craft 3.

---

If something goes wrong with a plugin installation you can usually disable or remove it in the `plugins` table in the db. To disable it you can set the column `plugins.enabled` to `0` in the row for the plugin you wish to disable.

Going a step farther you can delete the plugin's row from the `plugins` table and remove any related tables in the database that relate to that plugin. Be sure to backup your database before editing it directly.

After that, be sure to reach out to support for the respective developer and let them know what steps they can take to recreate the problem. You can contact Sprout support at: sprout@barrelstrengthdesign.com